# Is there a way to remove segment GNU_STACK

Tags: linux, gcc, binutils

I am trying to create a minimum executable using gcc/binutils.
My ld scripts is as below:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-x86-64", "elf64-x86-64",
              "elf64-x86-64")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:x86-64)
ENTRY(_start)
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib64/binutils/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/2.35.164"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/local/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib64/binutils/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/2.35.1"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/local/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib");
SECTIONS
{
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  .text           :
  {
    *(.text.unlikely .text.*_unlikely .text.unlikely.*)
    *(.text.exit .text.exit.*)
    *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
    *(.text.hot .text.hot.*)
    *(SORT(.text.sorted.*))
    *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf.em.  */
    *(.gnu.warning)
  }

  .data           :
  {
    *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
    SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
  }
  .bss            :
  {
   *(.dynbss)
   *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
   *(COMMON)
  }
}
```

Everything is OK for me, except that I see a extra segment header named "GNU_STACK" with size 0.
The header increases 56 bytes of course. Does anyone know how to remove it? Creating elf by hand is crazy, I want to use gcc/binutils to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like no way to do it. Finally I modified binutils source to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: the `GNU_STACK` ELF program header entry is required to mark the stack as not executable on legacy systems (32-bits x86, arm and powerpc, for example). If you remove it, the stack will be automatically marked as executable by the kernel:

[linux-5.17/arch/arm/kernel.elf.c#n80](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/elf.c?h=v5.17&id=f443e374ae131c168a065ea1748feac6b2e76613#n80)

In modern architectures GNU_STACK is not needed, so your linker script should be modified with the following:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-x86-64", "elf64-x86-64",
              "elf64-x86-64")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:x86-64)
ENTRY(_start)
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib64/binutils/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/2.35.164"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/local/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib64/binutils/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/2.35.1"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/local/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib");

PHDRS
{
    READONLY PT_LOAD FILEHDR PHDRS;
    READWRITE PT_LOAD;
}

SECTIONS
{
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  .text           :
  {
    *(.text.unlikely .text.*_unlikely .text.unlikely.*)
    *(.text.exit .text.exit.*)
    *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
    *(.text.hot .text.hot.*)
    *(SORT(.text.sorted.*))
    *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf.em.  */
    *(.gnu.warning)
  } : READONLY

  . = ALIGN(0x1000);

  .data           :
  {
    *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
    SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
  } : READWRITE
  .bss            :
  {
   *(.dynbss)
   *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
   *(COMMON)
  }
}
```

Change the `PHDRS` configuration as you prefer.

If you remove the `GNU_STACK` entry, you should probably use the `-Wtrampoline` or `-fno-trampolines` compiler flags:

[3.8 Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options)

[3.17 Options for Code Generation Conventions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options)